# Browse Source in trac

Tags: trac

When I click Browse Source in trac,it shows:

`No files found.`

How can I do it to show my java files?
For example:
In Which directory I should store my java files?

Thanks.

Comment: You will get better answers to your questions if you go back and accept the best answers to your older questions (click the check mark next to it).

Answer (score 0):

'Browse source" in trac means browsing some source that are stored in some VCS - version control system. Like Git, Subversion, mercurial etc etc.

So you need

- commit you java files into some vcs
- setup trac for that vcs (set type of vcs and directory) in the trac.ini

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what to do? I have subversion installed on my pc. So, where should i store my java files? Also, what changes should I do in my trac.ini file?

Comment: Creating a repository, committing files to it, all this is outside a simple question like this one. You find HowTo's about it everywhere, for SVN i.e. the SVN book (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014681/browse-source-in-trac). Configuring Trac to recognize your local(!) repository for browsing it is covered by existing authoritiative Trac wiki docs (http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBrowser) too. What else? :-)

Comment: Does it mean that i should not copy my java files to that folder? Should I commit them by tortoisesvn?

Comment: Yes, you are going to need to commit them to SVN with tortoisesvn in order to get the browse source to start working within Trac.